# How to integrate apple payment gateway with iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to payment in apple store from the iphone. So I want to make this type of application in which I can pay the amount to the apple store? But I dont know how it possible.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, this probably belongs on SO.

Comment: Sounds a lot like:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391029

Answer (score 2):

See the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Overview%20of%20the%20Store%20Kit%20API/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1).