# How to integrate apple payment gateway in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, payment-gateway

I want to integrate Apple Payment Gateway with my iPhone app.

i.e

Suppose user wants to purchase gold from the online store.
He/she can do payment through apple payment gatway.

If anybody knows then please give me advice/guidance.

Comment: There's a run on payment gateways:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391029/how-to-implement-payment-gateway-integration-with-iphone
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384490/how-to-integrate-payment-gateway-with-iphone
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403105/how-to-integrate-apple-payment-gateway-with-iphone
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395077/how-to-ima-plement-payment-gateway-integration-with-iphone-closed
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422948/how-to-integrate-apple-payment-gate-way-with-iphone

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to read through the [Store Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and the [Store Kit Type Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKitTypes/Reference/reference.html)